# Why does my HTPC's HDTV refresh rate go to 23hz when powering on (sometimes)?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-center, hdtv, netflix, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an HTPC connected with an HDTV through a receiver, and sometimes when turning the TV on, the refresh rate is set to 23hz instead of my setting of 60hz

- OS: Vista Home Premium (32bit).
- Graphics card: nVidia 8800GT, driver version 8.15.11.8618 release 6/10/2009.
- Receiver: Onkyo TX-SR705.
- HDTV: Samsung 50" DLP HLT5087SAX.
- Connection: DVI -> HDMI cable to receiver, HDMI -> HDMI receiver to TV.

This setup has been up and running for a year and a half now without this issue until recently. I **think** it might have been the latest nVidia driver update. It might be only happening when the Official Netflix plugin for Media Center is running. Those are the only "recent" changes I can think of that might have an effect.

I do not have anything set to automatically put the display or computer to sleep; I manually turn the TV off when I'm done watching. It should just run all the time at the setting I specify, but often when I turn it on, there it is at 23hz. I think it has done this when Media Center is in other views/plugins than Netflix, but I don't recall exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the video driver to the latest from nvidia's site seems to have resolve the issue. The previous drivers were the WHQL version that Vista automatically picked up.